# AWS Lambda subprocess curl not working despite terminal does, neither request does

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, curl, subprocess

I have an `AWS Lambda` that runs a curl request using `subprocess`.

**Subprocess call**

```
result = subprocess.call("curl -X \
                                 POST localhost:8080 \
                                 -H 'Cache-Control:no-cache' \
                                 -H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
                                 -d "+params+"")
```

Params is `params='{"conf":"{\"my_file\":\"'+file_path+'\"}"}'`

If I run the below `curl` request in terminal it works:

```
curl -X POST \
localhost:8080 \
-H 'Cache-Control:no-cache' \
-H 'Content-Type:application/json' \
-d '{"conf":"{\"my_file\":\"file_path\"}"}'
```

If I print my request in cloudwatch it returns:

```
curl -X                                  POST localhost:8080                                  -H 'Cache-Control:no-cache'                                  -H 'Content-Type:application/json'                                  -d {"conf":"{"my_file":"file_path"}"}
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/splits.py", line 40, in handler
    raise e
  File "/var/task/splits.py", line 23, in handler
    -d "+params+"")
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 339, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
```

I tested the `file_path` value in the `terminal request`s and it works, so the file exists.

Any suggestion?

**Edit**

Using `requests` attempt

```
params = {"conf":{"file_path":file}}



        url = "url"
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}
        data = params

        r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)

        print("r")
        print(r)
```

It returns:

```
<Response [400]>
```

But no other error trae is known.

Comment: Why are you not using the `requests` library?

Comment: @paolo because its not in lambda

Comment: Can't you include it in the `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: yes, i could, but i dont want to install nothing

Comment: @Paolo I changed it to requests, added the code in the question